# How to import a globally installed package to virtualenv folder

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

So I have a virtualenv folder called venv for my python project.

I can run:

```
venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Which installs all requirements I need for the project except one, M2Crypto. The only way to install it is through apt-get:

```
apt-get install python-m2crypto
```

How can I then add this package installed through apt to venv folder?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What I did after all:

```
cp -R /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/M2Crypto /home/richard/hello-project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
cp -R /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL /home/richard/hello-project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Comment: This should be built into virtual env

Comment: yes, I wonder if there is a virualenv method of installing into the environment the system-wide packages installed onto the host after that environment was already created.

Answer (score 47):

```
--system-site-packages
```

gives access to the global site-packages modules to the virtual environment.

you could do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-m2crypto
$ virtualenv env --system-site-packages
```

... and you would then have access to `m2crypto` (along with all other system-wide installed packages) inside your virtualenv.

Comment: As long as you are careful to only install packages you want shared globally in to the base python install, this is the way to go.

Comment: But then what is the point of using a virtual environment if it has access to global site packages?

Comment: Richard Knop, so you can install additional packages without root in your own virtualenv, and not mess with the system python.

Comment: If your virtual environment is already setup and you don't want to re-create it and you're using, or open to using, _virtualenvwrapper_ to manage your virtual environments, you can add access to `--system-site-packages` ex post facto by running the [`toggleglobalsitepackages` command](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#toggleglobalsitepackages).

Comment: @RichardKnop what is the point? 
here is an example. i have multiple projects different libraries but i use `auto_py_to_exe` for all of them

Answer (score 32):

Real simple solution.

In the virtual environment directory, edit the file `pyvenv.cfg`. Set the parameter  `include-system-site-packages = true`, and save the file. 
The globally installed modules will appear the next time you activate (`source venv/bin/activate`) your environment.

It can be verified via `pip list`.

Enjoy!

Comment: This is the only solution I could find that did not require sudo access. My issue was that I needed to import a pre-installed global package (which had required sudo) in a virtualenv in which I wanted to install additional packages in editable mode. This wasn't possible when creating the virtualenv with `--system-site-packages`. So this helped me a lot, thank you!

Comment: The appropriate solution for my scenario, which is a pretty standard one.

Answer (score 13):

`toggleglobalsitepackages` will toggle access to the system-wide `site-packages`.

**Note:** You need to [`pip install virtualenvwrapper`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to get this command; the vanilla `virtualenv` doesn't include it. With `virtualenvwrapper` you also get the very useful `mkvirtualenv` and `rmvirtualenv` commands, among others.

Comment: only if you install virtualenvwrapper. otherwise you get `toggleglobalsitepackages: command not found`

Comment: as of today, it is now `toggleglobalsitepackages`

Comment: `virtualenvwrapper` is installed but I still get `toggleglobalsitepackages: command not found`. Those virtualenv folks really needed to design this better. Seems like a basic necessary feature IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

```
venv/bin/pip install -I M2Crypto
```

The `-I` forces it to also be installed into the virtualenv, even if it's already globally installed.

Comment: I will try that. Why is it not documented in output from pip --help.

Comment: It's documented in `pip help install`. The `-I` flag is specific to the `install` command and thus not shown in the global flags list (there are many other command-specific flags).

Comment: Thanks. This is not working very well. You see, M2Crypto can actually be installed through pip but there is a bug in the library which makes the installation fail on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. They released a patch but it's not working for me... So when I try your command, it tries to download the library from pip repository and install it instead of just copying the apt package.

Comment: In that case, you'll probably want to use `--system-site-packages` for this one instance.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to transfer packages locally from one environment or global to the other virtual environment is
Copying the the "**Lib**"folder or the package folder with all its contents from the environment to the other environment you want the package to work

*If you don't know it's location search for it within the environment folder using file explorer*

**Lib** folder contains all the installed packages of the environment