# Do I need to reinstall everything from scratch in Virtual Environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv

My computer already has Tensorflow. Now I want to create a virtualenv to work inside it. So do I need to re-install Tensorflow inside the virtual environment or can I use the Tensorflow that was already installed outside?

The same questions with skimage, numpy, etc packages? Do I need to reinstall all of them for the virtual environment I just created? All of them have been installed outside.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992214/how-to-import-a-globally-installed-package-to-virtualenv-folder)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import a globally installed package to virtualenv folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992214/how-to-import-a-globally-installed-package-to-virtualenv-folder)

Comment: Just trying to import a library from the virtualenv should have answered your question